# React Native paper tabs Label color change

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-paper

Hi is there any possibily To change label color for each tab ? No icon needed.
For example first red then blue green etc.

- EXPLORE - red
- FLIGHTS - blue
- TRIPS - green

```
 import {
    TabScreen,
    Tabs,
    useTabIndex,
    useTabNavigation,
} from 'react-native-paper-tabs';

    export const PresentListScreen = observer(({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <Tabs
                // defaultIndex={0} // default = 0
                // uppercase={false} // true/false | default=true | labels are uppercase
                // showTextLabel={false} // true/false | default=false (KEEP PROVIDING LABEL WE USE IT AS KEY INTERNALLY + SCREEN READERS)
                // iconPosition // leading, top | default=leading
                // style={{ backgroundColor:'#fff' }} // works the same as AppBar in react-native-paper
                // dark={false} // works the same as AppBar in react-native-paper
                // theme={} // works the same as AppBar in react-native-paper
                // mode="scrollable" // fixed, scrollable | default=fixed
                // onChangeIndex={(newIndex) => {}} // react on index change
                
            >
                <TabScreen label="Explore" icon="compass">
                    <ExploreWitHookExamples />
                </TabScreen>
                <TabScreen label="Flights" icon="airplane">
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', flex: 1 }} />
                </TabScreen>
                <TabScreen label="Trips" icon="bag-suitcase">
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1 }} />
                </TabScreen>
            </Tabs>
            </SafeAreaView>
    );
});

[attached][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryk0Z.jpg
```